# cin statement being skipped

Tags: c++, struct, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct fruitType {
        int sugar;
        string name;
        string color;
        bool isSuperfood;
        string random;
};
    fruitType fruit;

    cout << "Enter the name of the fruit.";
    cin >> fruit.name;
    cout << endl << "What is the color of the fruit?";
    cin >> fruit.color;
    cout << endl << "Is it a superfood? Answer true or false.";
    cin >> fruit.isSuperfood;
    cout << endl << "How much sugar (in grams) does the fruit have?";
    cin >> fruit.sugar;
}
```

My fruit.sugar cin function is not working. When I run the program it skips that cin statement. I tried initializing sugar before the cin statement but got the same result. any help would be helpful.

My inputs are "watermelon", "green", and "true". I can't input anything for the sugar statement.

Comment: Please supply the inputs you are providing to the program.

Comment: Check the state of cin after each of the input operations! (`if (! cin) { ...` )

Comment: My inputs are watermelon, green, and true. I can't input anything for the sugar statement.

Comment: `cin >> fruit.isSuperfood;` is not compatible with the input string true / false, because of that *cin* is in error and you cannot read again until you clear the error (and may be flush the unexpected input). You need to read a string then compare it with true/false to set your bool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
cout << endl << "Is it a superfood? Answer true or false.";
cin >> fruit.isSuperfood;
```

The type of `isSuperfood` is a boolean and your assumption is that the program would accept the string `"true"` and `"false"`, but it's not in actual. Rather, the program will understand true for `bool` if you enter `1`, otherwise false when entered `0`.

Use strings here that accept the words like `"true"`, `"false"`, `"something"`, etc, and write a condition which will accept only `"true"` and `"false"`:

```
std::string isSuperFood;

// verifying if the input is valid
if (!(std::cin >> isSuperFood)) {
    std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

if (isSuperFood == "true" || isSuperFood == "false")
    std::cout << "OK";
else
    std::cout << "Not OK";
```

You could say that `true` for `bool` holds `1`, OTOH, `false` holds `0`.